# Get element's html tag content

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is it possible to get a node's top-level tag html via the dom api?  To be clear, if I have

```
<div data-x="a">
    <span>Hello</span>
</div>
```

I want to just get back `<div data-x="a">`

Is a crude string matching on outerHTML the best I can do, or is there a fast and direct way to achieve what I want?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'd call the matching crude…the DOM will always be a tree, so having to do some pruning doesn't seem unacceptable. Just make a reusable function getTopTag or something and call it a day.

Comment: @Thomas - true, not terribly crude.  Was just hoping there was a direct way that I was missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you clone the node, the innerHTML property will be empty.
For your example, a shallow clone is appropriate (pass `false` or don't pass anything).

```js
// get the div element
var element = document.querySelectorAll('div')[0];

// view the outerHTML of the element
console.log('original outerHTML', element.outerHTML);

// clone the element
var clone = element.cloneNode();

// view the outerHTML of the clone
console.log('outerHTML of clone', clone.outerHTML); // has what you want
```

```html
<div data-x="a">
    <span>Hello</span>
</div>
```

[.cloneNode() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)

Comment: Thanks - I edited because the comments in your code appeared to be wrong - sorry if *I* was wrong - but the code look great - thanks.

Comment: No worries.  I threw it together pretty quickly.

Comment: Added a link to the MDN documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the outerHTML to get all of it, and the innerHTML to get the stuff just inside.  Then do a string replace on the outerHTML, replacing the innerHTML with an empty string, and doing the same for the end tag.